# Why this Spark code works in local mode but not in cluster mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, I have something like this. Note that `baseTrait` (a trait) here is serializable, and therefore `thisClass` (an Object class) should also be serializable.

```
object thisClass extends baseTrait {
  private var someVar = null 

  def someFunc: RDD[...] {
    ...
    // assigned some string value or an empty string value (not null anymore)
    someVar = ... 
    ...
    if (someVar != "")
      someRDD.filter(x => aFunc(x, someVar))
    else
      ...
  }
```

In cluster mode, when I call the `someFunc` function (which is a static method since `thisClass` is an Object class) I get a null pointer exception, which I think has to do with `someVar` not being serialized properly. Because when I do this, it works perfectly in cluster mode.

```
if (someVar != "") {
  val someVar_ = someVar
  someRDD.filter(x => aFunc(x, someVar_))
}
```

Any idea what was going wrong in the original code, when `thisClass` is serializable in the first place?

My guess is that its fine to use a variable of a serializable class from within another class, but if you try to do it inside that class, you can have problems, as in that case you would have the runtime trying to serialize the same class where the closure is being called from. What do you think?

Comment: Can you show the driver code that is instantiating and using `thisClass`?

Comment: Well it just calls the someFunc function, which is kind of a static method, since this is an Object class.

Comment: Not too sure how closures capture values in scala, but I suppose this has to do with the difference between local-scoped and instance fields capturing in closures (when the closure is declared in a function) - i.e., I suspect in the case of `_someVar`, the instance isn't captured (that's my vague guess)

Comment: @ernest_k I am getting what you are saying. Basically, you are saying that if you use a serializable class in a closure from another class, it should be fine, but if you are using a local variable of a serializable class inside that class (from a closure that is), you can have problems.

Comment: Not basically saying anything I can back up. But if I were you, I would start with [Understanding closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) from the spark documentation. It seems to contrast local vs cluster modes

Comment: @ernest_k Very useful link. Thanks for sharing. But the example they gave is that of mutating a variable, while I just read a variable.

Comment: @MetallicPriest - I think the documentation provided from @ernest_k is still relevant: `In general, closures - constructs like loops or locally defined methods, should not be used to mutate some global state. Spark does not define or guarantee the behavior of mutations to objects referenced from outside of closures.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not experiencing a problem with serialization in this case.

Basically, what happens in cluster mode is that `thisClass.someFunc` is never actually executed in the remote executor's JVM. On the executor, `thisClass` is instantiated, and `someVar` is assigned `null`. Then while the `thisClass` object is in that state, the spark framework executes your lambda function directly on the records that are available in that executor's partition of the data.

A way to avoid this is to move the assignment to `someVar` into the body of the `thisClass` object. Doing that will assign the value to `someVar` immediately when the object is instantiated. Bear in mind that this code will be executed on *every* executor in the cluster.

If that is not possible, another option would be to map your `RDD[T]` to `RDD[(T, String)]`, where the string is `someVar` for every record, and then your filter could be something like `.filter(x => aFunc(x._1, x._2))`. This method will use more memory, as you'll have many copies of `someVar`'s value.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well observed :). And I agree with your solutions. What also worked for me is to assign a variable to thisClass.someVar and use that variable inside the lambda. In that case Spark just needs to serialize that string.